# trying to get the individual count of column count

Tags: sql

```
eid  name
1   john
2    pal
3   mike
4   michel

id eid   mobile     address
1   1   9640253265
2   2   9632587412  hellpp
3   3               poplop
4   4   9638523690           
5   1   9632589632
6   2                addr
```

how to get the below output

```
name   mobilecount  addresscount
john   2                0
pal    1                2
mike   0                1
michel 1                0
```

Comment: You should format your text, and be more precise about what you need. Also, it would help if you posted the table structures, and maybe show us what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       COUNT(mobile) AS mobilecount, 
       COUNT(address) AS addresscount
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.eid = t2.eid
GROUP BY t1.name
```

The above query depends on `COUNT` function not counting `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
select name,SUM(mobilecount) as mobilecount,SUM(addresscount) as addresscount
from
(
  select t1.name,
  case when isnull(t2.mobile,'')<>'' then count(mobile) else 0 end as     
  mobilecount,
  case when isnull(t2.address,'')<>'' then count(mobile) else 0 end as     
  addresscount
  from table1 t1,table2 t2
  where t1.eid = t2.eid
  group by t1.name,t2.mobile,t2.address
)employee
group by name order by name
```